# Scaling Elasticsearch via large shard count

Tags: elasticsearch

I am interested in setting up an Elasticsearch cluster. Initially, there will be very few nodes (i.e. 3 nodes), but the plan is eventually to scale it up to many thousands of nodes. The documentation states that: "The number of primary shards is fixed at the moment an index is created." This means that if I start with three shards, I cannot get any advantages by adding more nodes later. Does this mean that I should create my index with 10,000 shards initially, even though I only have 3 nodes initially? This will give me the ability to scale up to 10,000 nodes, right?

Comment: For the first question, of course not! You benchmark and set the appropriate number of shards. And if you want to add a node or two you won't be loosing any performance. Nevertheless if you need to add 10000 nodes. You'll have to benchmark again and choose. Elasticsearch is very easily scalable by adding nodes alone generally.

Comment: The documentation says that: `You cannot change the number of primary shards in an index, once the index is created` This means I can't add more nodes without recreating the index unless I have many shards at the start.

Comment: You'll have to recreate the index again thus re-index if you want to change the numbers of shards. All I have said is that you have to benchmark to decide on the number of shards.

Comment: And of course re-indexing can't be done with a zero downtime.

Comment: I understand that, but I have seasonal traffic that differs by orders of magnitude. I was hoping to have a system that I can scale with 0 downtime. If this is really the case, there is nothing "elastic" about elasticsearch.

Comment: Unfortunately it's doesn't do 0 downtime. But that doesn't mean it's not elastic. Elasticity is assured with nodes not shards. They never pretend it was. One more thing, mainly 5 shards are usually a good fit. Dailymotion benchmarked performance over shard count and the study gave 5 as the best trade-off

Comment: Actually the number of nodes do not need to equal the number of shards(primary or replica) . Scaling up here means add new nodes but not add new shards. In practice we set more shards and less nodes when setting up a new elasticsearch cluster .   5 is only a default setting . If you have only one node, 1 shard works well .

Answer (score 0):

You can try the _split api to scale up and the _shrink api to scale down.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/indices-split-index.html#

```
POST my_source_index/_split/my_target_index?copy_settings=true
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 50 
  }
}
```